# Ubuntu 18.04 Stuck in Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispacher Service....after trying to crate a swap file

Tags: 18.04, gnome, swap

Here is the screen image--- [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Jo4.jpg

I tried to create a swap file to use it for hibernation.

My PC is Dual Booted with Windows and Ubuntu

CPU: Intel Pentium Dual Core 3.2 GHz

RAM: 4GB

Disk Space:10.4GB

I used `sudo fallocate -l 4g /swapfile`

Only 2.2 GB was left
The disk was full with 0kb left
After that it stuck with Started GNOME Display Manager

[EDIT]--
I am thinking  of reinstalling it

I can access all of it's folders and user data from windows.

Should I copy the Home folder to a USB and replace it with the one in the newly installed Ubuntu???
I want to migrate all installed programs.

[EDIT 2]--  Also there is around 400mb free sapce after removing some files in recovery mode then also it is not booting up.

Comment: A Ubuntu OS will not start with zero free disk space.

Comment: I know that but how do I fix this?

Comment: How big was the partition you installed Ubuntu into? It needed to be at least 25 gig. The rule for swap files is 2 times the size of the ram. With a machine this slow it is unlikely a swap file would make it faster. Assuming there are files you can delete you need to boot from Live Media and delete them.

Comment: The partition size is 10.4gigs and swap partition is 5.2gig

Comment: reboot into `Recovery` then from menu choose root terminal so you can issue the commands to fix the issue

Comment: Then sorry there is little point in trying to fix it. The min partition size is 25 gig. It will fail again with zero disk space in little time.  Of course you can do as you feel is the right way to go.

Comment: What you might try is a lighter weight version like Lubuntu. 
The recommended system requirements are: CPU: 1 gigahertz or better. RAM: 1 gigabyte or more. Disk: a minimum of 2.5 gigabytes.

Comment: What if I increase the  Ubuntu partition size using  the dual booted widows will it fix the problem?